# My Samsung galaxy s5 seems to be half rooted

Tags: rooting, samsung

I recently factory reset my rooted Samsung Galaxy s5. The problem that I am now having is that to apps such as my Internet browser and androad pay disable features on the grounds that my phone is rooted, but other apps such as supersu do not act as if my phone was rooted.

How should I fix this problem. I am currently experiencing all the disadvantags of rooting but none of the positives so a fix in either direction would be great.

Comment: You should consider flashing a stock firmware/ROM to solve this

Answer (score 0):

try either rooting completely, or removing any custom stuff(kernel, bootloader etc).
if that doesnt work try flashing the stock ROM manually.

Answer (score 0):

Knox would have been tripped when you rooted. Unfortunately, (if I remember correctly) you can't easily untrip it. It will keep failing SafetyNet, so you'd just be best off going back to a full root and taking those benefits.